# Не получается "склеить" кортежи в python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет!
Почему-то не получается склеить кортежи на выходе функции

```
a = ''.join(map(str, permutations('random', 6)))
```

т.е. вот на таком кусочке всё работает отлично:

```
a = ('r', 'a', 'n', 'd', 'o', 'm')
print(''.join(a))
```

А для всех вариаций на тему, почему-то нет:(
Что я делаю не так? И как можно сделать по-другому?
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from itertools import permutations

print(*[ ''.join(i) for i in permutations('random', 6)], sep='\n')
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!!

Answer (score 0):

Может вот так?

```
a = list(map(''.join, list(permutations('random', 6))))
```